# partial differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{xy}} \cdot g\left( \frac x y \right)$$

$$x>0 , y >0$$

$$x\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} +y\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}+f =0$$

Am asked to show that f solves the partial differential equation.

How to take the partial derivative of the product of 2 functions each depends on two variables ?

I hope I was clear about the difficulty I have , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Partial derivative of a product is the same as with differentiating a product except you do with respect to the specified variable. For example:

$(fg)_x = f_x g + f g_x$